# How to set a flattened test/source folder structure?

Tags: gradle

Using gradle for a Java+Groovy+JUnit project, I get this source folder structure by default:

```
prjroot-src
├── main
│   ├── groovy
│   └── java
└── test
    ├── groovy
    └── java
```

I wanted to have Java and Groovy sources in one folder, so I set the `sourceSets` like this:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs += ["src/main/java"]
```

Which resulted in the same directory structure with the difference that I could put my .groovy files in the java folder. Also, the unused Groovy folder still is there.

I'd like a much flatter, cleaner directory structure that looks like this:

```
prjroot
├── src
└── test
```

The packages, .groovy and .java files should be directly under src, and the test sources accordingly under test.

How can I achieve this using gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `sourceSets` code with:

```
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs = ["src"]
sourceSets.test.groovy.srcDirs = ["test"]
```